# Issues during Soapui and Jenkins integration

Tags: jenkins, maven-plugin, soapui

I am trying to integrate Soapui open source version 4.5.1 with Maven & then finally trying to make it run from CI.

But unfortunately the test classes are executing fine both from eclipse and command line in local system but fails in CI with this message:

```
16:58:34  16:58:34,323 INFO  [WsdlProject] Loaded project from [file:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/rps_deals30_unittests_automation_priya/workspace/RPService/src/test/resources/serviceautomation/GService-Deals-Test-soapui-project.xml]
16:58:36  java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
16:58:36    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:240)
    16:58:36    at     sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:193)
    16:58:36    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:262)
    16:58:36    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:216)
    16:58:36    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:411)
    16:58:36    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:478)
    16:58:36    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:1003)
    ...
    ...
```

This is the relevant snippet from my pom.xml file:

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>eviware</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <id>soapui-tests</id>
                <configuration>
                    <projectFile>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/serviceautomation/GService-Deals-Test-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                    <outputFolder>${basedir}/target/soapui</outputFolder>
                    <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                    <exportwAll>true</exportwAll>
                    <printReport>true</printReport>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration></configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you got that pom configuration from, or what you are trying to do. Using the recommended pom from the the official [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html#1-Basic-Configuration), you should just have:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>eviware</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <projectFile>src/test/resources/serviceautomation/GService-Deals-Test-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
        <outputFolder>target/soapui</outputFolder>
        <junitReport>true</junitReport>
        <exportwAll>true</exportwAll>
        <printReport>true</printReport>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Skip all the `executions` specific things, that is what causing your problems.